# MySQL “lost” all data (InnoBD)

Tags: debian, mysql, database

Today I was making some work with site and I get error what MySQL can't rename file (to make changes in BD). Next I tried to restart MySQL, and it failed to stop MySQL. Then I did go to `/var/lib/mysql` and all I see is: `ib_logfile0+1`, `ibdata1`, and `site` folder, with tables that I was changing (not tables themselves, just `#sql-b61_25a8e.MYI`).

Can I recover my MySQL data? I don't need all tables, because I have old backup of them. I just need that one table with all users (I was changing table with users). And yes, I did shutdown MySQL for some stupid reason.

Comment: perhaps better asked at stackoverflow.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810413/mysql-lost-all-datainnobd lol,they are sending me to here,and you sending me to there...

Comment: @Tomas I'm pretty much sure this is the right place. Configuring and recovering databases are on-topic here. Specifics of SQL queries obviously belong to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Have you tried [force recovery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)? This may allow MySQL to start up so that you can dump/backup the users table, but won't allow changes. Also, the MySQL error log -- starting with the crash -- would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, where are your backups? If you don't have any, this should be your first task after recovering your data.

Anyhow, as long as you have a copy of your .frm files, you *can* recover the data. Those files are usually located in the same directory as you DB data, e. g. /var/lib/mysql, but maybe your setup differs. If you have no copy of your .frm files, you need to re-create them. frm-files statically store your table layout, so shouldn't be too hard to re-create, provided you have kept your design papers or you use a provided application such as Wordpress. Then just create new instance of the application and copy the frm-files to your recovery machine.

For recovery follow these simple steps:

1. Set up a new MySQL server on another machine, but do not start `mysqld` yet.
2. Copy your `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` to the new machine's `/var/lib/mysql` folder.
3. Make sure that these files belong to the MySQL user, e. g. `chown mysql ibdata1 ...`
4. Find the size of the logfiles in bytes, e. g. `ls -l`.
5. Become the MySQL user, e. g. `su mysql`.
6. Start the mysqld with recovery options, i. e. `/usr/sbin/mysqld –innodb_log_file_size=<size_inbytes> –innodb_force_recovery=6`

Now you should see some messages from MySQL, such as which options you set. After a short while `mysqld` should be up and running. Once this has happened you can pull a correct copy of your database with `mysqldump` and import the copy into your production machine.

Comment: yea that is right answer,but i get it also at ServerFault.Becaos that is right answer,then lets mark you as right answer ;)